# I can't connect mongodb with django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, database

I use mongoengine. and below is my settings:

```
    _MONGODB_USER = 'user1'
    _MONGODB_PASSWD = '12345678'
    _MONGODB_HOST = 'mongodb://user1:damian123@ds99999.mlab.com:23932/projekt_dkjp'
    _MONGODB_NAME = 'baza1'
    _MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
        'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
        % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)
    mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_HOST)
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': '',
        },

}
```

and when i run server i see this problem:

```
      File "C:\Users\vbox\PycharmProjects\Projekt06\projekt\projekt\settings.py", line 90, in 
        mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_HOST)
      File "C:\Users\vbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\connection.py", line 165, in connect
        return get_connection(alias)
      File "C:\Users\vbox\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\connection.py", line 128, in get_connection
        raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
    mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
    False is not a read preference.
```

Comment: What versions of python and pymongo and mongoengine are you using? Have a look at this GitHub issue -> https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/950

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://<URL>',
            'username': 'something',
            'password': 'somepass',
            'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain why this is helpful

Comment: @wahwahwah , it took me while to figure it out aswell, the docs on djongo are kind of complex but this snippet works for me every time :)

Answer (score -1):

Basically, DATABASES should look something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
   } 
}
```

Source: [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases)

Easy to understand picture:

[image]

A simple doc to understand can be found [here](http://ftparmy.com/272498-django-mongokit@imagedjango-mongokit-02.jpg.html)